# Issues with latin chars encoding in Oracle table

Tags: oracle, character-encoding, char

I have an oracle database with

```
NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8  

sqlplus nls_lang is WE8ISO8859P1
```

unix shell is iso aswell

There is varchar2 column with letter: *LATIN SMALL LETTER O WITH ACUTE*

When I call DUMP function on this column I get:

```
Typ=1 Len=4: 195,131,194,179
```

This doesn't look like UTF8.

Running SELECT shows corrupted cha on screen.

Running `CONVERT(VALUE, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'UTF8')` - shows correct value, but the encoding doesn't look like UTF8...

---

If I try to insert same letter manually, the select query returns correct char.

The Dump shows 195,179 which is correct UTF8 code.

Running `CONVERT(VALUE, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'UTF8')` - fails
ORA-29275: partial multibyte character

Which is strange because 195,179  is indeed UTF8.

Please clarify the above to me.

Comment: What do you get from `DUMP(..., 1016)`?

Comment: `CONVERT(VALUE, 'UTF8', 'WE8ISO8859P1')` is wrong, i.e. this means "Convert **from** `WE8ISO8859P1` **to** `UTF8`" - however, your value is already UTF-8 according `NLS_CHARACTERSET`

Comment: For value that already existed I get: Typ=1 Len=4 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,83,c2,b3  

for new value that I inserted I get:
Typ=1 Len=2 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,b3

Comment: I am sorry , I pasted wrong convert, the original that I used was 
 CONVERT(VALUE, 'WE8ISO8859P1', 'UTF8'), after that I did some test so I switched places...

I will update question

Comment: Which client do you use to insert and query the data?

Comment: I use sqlplus only

Answer (score 1):

Value `Typ=1 Len=4 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,83,c2,b3` was obviously inserted wrongly.

It happened when the client sent the characters as UTF-8 but the database treated this data as WE8ISO8859P1.

If the client sends data as UTF-8 then you must also set `NLS_LANG=.AL32UTF8` (language and territory are optional and not relevant here).

However when you run sqlplus then sqlplus inherits character set from command line which seems to be ISO 8859-1. So before you start sqlplus you must run `export NLS_LANG=.WE8ISO8859P1` in order to set it properly.

I create a table with your data:

```
SELECT 
    val, 
    DUMP(val, 1016) as dump_val, 
    DUMP(CONVERT(VAL, 'WE8ISO8859P1'), 1016) as conv_dump
FROM AA;


+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|VAL|DUMP_VAL                                      |CONV_DUMP                               |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|Ã³ |Typ=1 Len=4 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,83,c2,b3|Typ=1 Len=2 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,b3|
|ó  |Typ=1 Len=2 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: c3,b3      |Typ=1 Len=1 CharacterSet=AL32UTF8: f3   |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Row 1 shows corrupt data, row 2 is fine.

`CONVERT(VAL, 'WE8ISO8859P1')` is used to convert corrupt data to correct character set, so conversion of `CONVERT(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('C383C2B3'), 'WE8ISO8859P1')` is fine.

However `CONVERT(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_VARCHAR2('C3B3'), 'WE8ISO8859P1')` would return hex `F3` which is not a valid UTF-8 byte sequence, thus you get an ORA-29275.

Comment: Still not clear,  ' database treated this data as WE8ISO8859P1'  but NLS_CHARACTERSET=AL32UTF8.
c3,83,c2,b3  'is obviously wrong', but why covert worked for this and didn't work for 195,179  which is true UTF8?

Comment: Yes, but when "for value that already existed" was inserted (perhaps by somebody else) then NLS_LANG was set wrong.

Comment: Yes this is true! it was inserted with some other NLS_LANG  (don't know which).
Why the data that I inserted manually, and looks like UTF8 encoding 195,179  , why convert function is not working, and why it  did work for 195,131,194,179?

Comment: regarding your update, 'c3,b3' is UTF-8 encoding, why CONVERT fails on it, I need to understand this part.
C383C2B3 - is not even a UTF8, no idea what is it.

Comment: Convert is mainly used to correct corrupt data (that's the only reason why one should use it). However 'C3B3' is not corrupt, there is nothing to correct.